# Add condition from view to sql in model

Tags: php, yii2

In view I add

```
<select name="list">
    <option value="mouse">mouse</option>
    <option value="keyboard">keyboard</option>
    <option value="headphones">headphones/option>
</select>`
```

In model I create `$list = "'mouse','keyboard','headphones'";`

How add condition, if user select 'mouse' than `where items_sort in ({$list})` where `$list` contains 'mouse'?

```
$result =  Yii::$app->getDb()->createCommand(
        "Select *
         from order_table
         where items_sort in ({$list})"
    )->queryAll();


    return $result;
}
```

Comment: get post data from user in controller and pass it into your model

Comment: @Roman could you show some example?

Answer (score 0):

Just as a general answer, I suppose you have a form with a `select` field named `list` which submit request to `order` action. Add a list argument to your action with default value:

```
public function actionOrder($list = "'mouse','keyboard','headphones'")
{
    $result =  Yii::$app->getDb()->createCommand(
            "Select *
             from order_table
             where items_sort in ({$list})"
        )->queryAll();

    return $this->render('order', ['order' => $result]);
}
```

It's just a solution, not even a good solution! A good candidate is implementing an `Order` model for your `order_table` table (and it's good if you remove `_table` prefix from this table name and name `items_sort` column to a singular name e.g. `item_sort`) and search in your action with an `ActiveRecord` model:

```
public function actionOrder($list = "'mouse','keyboard','headphones'")
{
    $result = Order::find()
        ->where(['items_sort' => $list])
        ->all();

    return $this->render('order', ['order' => $result]);
}
```